# Why is this basic solution to a differential equation correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I have asked questions before, and have read many questions and answers from others on stackexchange, about how to treat "$dx$" in a differential equation.

people often have the intuition of treating $dx$ in the term "$\frac{df}{dx}$" as if it were a separate subterm of that, even though $\frac{df}{dx}$, or at least $\frac{d}{dx}$ is an operator, and shouldn't be seen as a fraction of two seperable elements.

Nevertheless, when solving the simple differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=x$, people often proceed as follows:

> $$(a):\qquad \frac{dx}{dt}=x$$
>   **Step 1:** multiply by $dt$ and subtract by $x$:
>   $$(b):\qquad \frac{1}{x}dx=dt $$
>   **Step 2:** integrate both sides:
>   $$(c): \qquad \int\frac{1}{x}dx=\int dt$$
>   **Step 3:** Solve the integral:
>   $$(d): \qquad ln(x)=t+C\implies x=e^{t+C}=x_0e^t$$

**So my questions are**

1. we know that the justification of Step 1 as "**multiplication**" is incorrect, since $dx$ and $dt$ are not seperable elements, so **what is the justification for going from equation $(a)$ to $(c)$?**
2. When $a=b$, we can conclude that $\int adx=\int bdx$, since this takes the integral of both sides with respect to the same variable, but **What is the justification of inserting the integral sign in equation $(c)$, without also adding the differential $dx$ to both sides?**

Comment: From (a) to (c) you can do standard integration by substitution: $\int \frac1x \frac{dx}{dt} dt = \int \frac 1x dx$. How that is proven varies from book to book, but it can be done without interpreting $\frac{dx}{dt}$ as a fraction. I don't even know (b) means in a normal calculus class. Differential geometry, sure, but not calculus, or even analysis.

Comment: @Programmer2134: See near bottom of page 1: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~m3cod/klbookLectures/303unit/sep.pdf

Comment: @Moo, Thanks that was a really good reference.

Answer (score 0):

The proof hops over (b) and goes straight from (a) to (c).

Generally speaking we have (if $f(x)\not=0$):
$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=f(x)g(t)\Leftrightarrow \int\dfrac{1}{f(x)}dx = \int g(t)\,dt$$
since differentiating the RHS with respect to $t$ gives
$$\dfrac{1}{f(t)}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=g(t)$$
according to the chain rule.